# Symfony 3.3 project deployement

Tags: symfony

I've worked on Symfony 3.3 project in production mode in localhost. I would like

to deploy it in development mode on remote server. So how can proceed to do that?

Can someone help me ?

thank you in advance !

Comment: what did you read? what have to tried? where are you stuck? please elaborate a lot more details, thanks.

Comment: Note that keeping the dev environment on a server is a security issue

Comment: in localhost it works fine. But when i try to transfere it on remote server in development mode. I've HTTP ERROR 500 (Internal server error)

Comment: still you'll have to provide more details, otherwise we won't be able to support you

Answer (score 1):

Warning first, as goto said in the comments, using the dev environment on a remote server **is a security issue**. So, make sure it is a test server, or a very temporary solution when deploying the app for the first time on your prod server.

Being able to get the Symfony toolbar on a remote server helps a lot and lets you save time, especially if it's the first time you deploy and you get unexpected errors.

**1. Server configuration**

By default on the server, all requests are redirected to app.php (file located in the web/ directory of your project). You have to change this behaviour and tell the server to redirect to app_dev.php

Using Nginx, you'll have to change your configuration like this:

```
# Symfony fallback
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app_dev.php
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/app_dev\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    internal
}
```

Don't forget to test and reload Nginx config after you've made the changes:

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

I don't know about Apache but it should be something similar (replacing app.php by app_dev.php).

**2. Composer**

You have to run `composer install` on the remote server, without using the `--no-dev --optimize-autoloader` options. It will install the bundles that are needed in dev environment but normally not installed in prod environment.

**3. Cache**

Clear and warm up the cache with the dev option:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=dev
```

And you should be ready to go, open your browser and go to your website, you'll be in dev mode.

Note: although I think my answer should work, I've done this manipulation more than a year ago, and I cannot test it today.

Answer (score 0):

[Just read the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html)

Deploying a Symfony application can be a complex and varied task depending on
the setup and the requirements of your application. This article is not a step-
by-step guide, but is a general list of the most common requirements and ideas
for deployment.

### Symfony Deployment Basics

The typical steps taken while deploying a Symfony application include:

- Upload your code to the production server;
- Install your vendor dependencies (typically done via Composer and may be done
  before uploading);
- Running database migrations or similar tasks to update any changed data structures;
- Clearing (and optionally, warming up) your cache.

A deployment may also include other tasks, such as:

- Tagging a particular version of your code as a release in your source control
  repository;
- Creating a temporary staging area to build your updated setup "offline";
- Running any tests available to ensure code and/or server stability;
- Removal of any unnecessary files from the `public/` directory to keep your
  production environment clean;
- Clearing of external cache systems (like `Memcached`_ or `Redis`_).

### How to Deploy a Symfony Application

There are several ways you can deploy a Symfony application. Start with a few
basic deployment strategies and build up from there.

Basic File Transfer

The most basic way of deploying an application is copying the files manually
via FTP/SCP (or similar method). This has its disadvantages as you lack control
over the system as the upgrade progresses. This method also requires you
to take some manual steps after transferring the files (see `Common Post-Deployment Tasks`_)

Using Source Control

If you're using source control (e.g. Git or SVN), you can simplify by having
your live installation also be a copy of your repository. When you're ready to
upgrade it is as simple as fetching the latest updates from your source control
system. When using Git, a common approach is to create a tag for each release
and check out the appropriate tag on deployment (see `Git Tagging`_).

This makes updating your files *easier*, but you still need to worry about
manually taking other steps (see `Common Post-Deployment Tasks`_).

Using Platforms as a Service

Using a Platform as a Service (PaaS) can be a great way to deploy your Symfony app
quickly and easily. There are many PaaS - below are a few that work well with Symfony:

- Heroku
- Platform.sh
- Azure
- fortrabbit

Using Build Scripts and other Tools

There are also tools to help ease the pain of deployment. Some of them have been
specifically tailored to the requirements of Symfony.

`EasyDeployBundle`
    A Symfony bundle that adds easy deploy tools to your application.

`Deployer`
    This is another native PHP rewrite of Capistrano, with some ready recipes for
    Symfony.

`Ansistrano`
    An Ansible role that allows you to configure a powerful deploy via YAML files.

`Magallanes`
    This Capistrano-like deployment tool is built in PHP, and may be easier
    for PHP developers to extend for their needs.

`Fabric`
    This Python-based library provides a basic suite of operations for executing
    local or remote shell commands and uploading/downloading files.

`Capistrano` with `Symfony plugin`
    `Capistrano`_ is a remote server automation and deployment tool written in Ruby.
    `Symfony plugin`_ is a plugin to ease Symfony related tasks, inspired by `Capifony`_
    (which works only with Capistrano 2).

`sf2debpkg`
    Helps you build a native Debian package for your Symfony project.

Basic scripting
    You can of course use shell, `Ant`_ or any other build tool to script
    the deploying of your project.